# Grails app terminates after giving exception

Tags: java, grails

This is very strange that the application stops working after sometime and throws an error. Below are the details for same.

Any help would be worth

**OS** : ubuntu0.14.04.1

**Java Version** : Open JDK 7

**Grails Version** : 2.4.5

**Application Type** : Rest Application

**Error / Exception**

```
MISSING EXCEPTION HANDLER for pc 0x00007fa0613a429c and handler bci -1
   Exception:
java.lang.StackOverflowError 
 - klass: 'java/lang/StackOverflowError'
 Compiled exception table :
ExceptionHandlerTable (size = 288 bytes)
catch_pco = 344 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1329
catch_pco = 516 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1523
catch_pco = 532 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1528
catch_pco = 868 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1533
catch_pco = 920 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1535
catch_pco = 944 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1537
catch_pco = 1160 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1465
catch_pco = 1188 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1518
catch_pco = 1220 (1 entries)
  bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1513
catch_pco = 1340 (2 entries)
  bci 100 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1490
  bci 110 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1476
catch_pco = 1476 (2 entries)
  bci 100 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1550
  bci 110 at scope depth 0 -> pco 1476
Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (sharedRuntime.cpp:714), pid=19233, tid=140325521483520
#  guarantee(false) failed: missing exception handler
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_101) (build 1.7.0_101-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.95-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/vinay/Documents/projects/westcon/nimbus4/nimbus4-api/hs_err_pid19233.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

Comment: This seems like an error in JDK itself.

Comment: Did you fixed it? I'm getting same error and using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @fsi not yet! It still exists for  me.

Comment: i dont remember this error, but i fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It surfaced when I tried to run any grails command.

Running: grails 2.0.3, macOS 10.13.2.

Turns our the fix was to use JDK 1.7.

I had JDK 1.8 set as JAVA_HOME for a different project and forgot to switch it back to 1.7.

Hope this helps